# PYTHON - Unable To Find Xpath Using Selenium

Tags: python, xpath

I have been struggling with this for a while now.
I have tried various was of finding the xpath for the following highlighted HTML
I am trying to grab the dollar value listed under the highlighted Strong tag.
[image]

Here is what my last attempt looks like below:

```
try:
     price = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//table[@role='presentation']")
     price.find_element_by_xpath(".//tbody")
     price.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr")
     price.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[@align='right']")
     price.find_element_by_xpath(".//strong")
     print(price.get_attribute("text"))
except:
     print("Unable to find element text")
```

I attempted to access the table and all nested elements but I am still unable to access the highlighted portion. Using .text and get_attribute('text') also does not work.

Is there another way of accessing the nested element? 
Or maybe I am not using XPath as it properly should be. 
I have also tried the below:

```
 price = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]")
```

UPDATE:
Here is the Full Code of the Site.
The Site I am using here is www.concursolutions.com
I am attempting to automate booking a flight using selenium.
When you reach the end of the process of booking and receive the price I am unable to print out the price based on the HTML.
It may have something to do with the HTML being a java script that is executed as you proceed.

[image]

Comment: `print(price)` after each line in your try block to see what the value is.

Comment: can you paste the code or the site url?

Comment: @JacobIRR -- The print statement after each line in the try statement gives me this. selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="cb55ef0ef15ae87ad69885661840774b", element="0.5695520939701662-5") along with many more lines of this.

Comment: Try this expression to get the strong element `//div[@id="gdsfarequote"]/center/table/tbody/tr[14]/td[2]/strong`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Using your line provided i get this response: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="7f1948d9c7d27296001d568d0b9dc60e", element="0.8145617598530703-5")>

Comment: @Thefourthbird
UPDATE:
if i use your line as provided and then use print(price.text) it works!! Thanks so much ! If you had provided an answer I would upvote and select your answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the structure of the html, you could use this xpath expression:

`//div[@id="gdsfarequote"]/center/table/tbody/tr[14]/td[2]/strong`

Answer (score 1):

## Making it work

There are a few things keeping your code from working.

1. **`price.find_element_by_xpath(...)` returns a new element.**

   Each time, you're not saving it to use with your next query. Thus, when you finally ask it for its text, you're still asking the  `<table>` element—not the `<strong>` element.

   Instead, you'll need to save each found element in order to use it as the scope for the next query:

   ```py
   table = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//table[@role='presentation']")
   tbody = table.find_element_by_xpath(".//tbody")
   tr = tbody.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr")
   td = tr.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[@align='right']")
   strong = td.find_element_by_xpath(".//strong")
   ```
2. **`find_element_by_*` returns the first matching element.**

   This means your call to `tbody.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr")` will return the first `<tr>` element in the `<tbody>`.

   Instead, it looks like you want the third:

   ```py
   tr = tbody.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr[3]")
   ```

   Note: XPath is 1-indexed.
3. **`get_attribute(...)` returns HTML element attributes.**

   Therefore, `get_attribute("text")` will return the value of the `text` attribute on the element.

   To return the text *content* of the element, use `element.text`:

   ```py
   strong.text
   ```

## Cleaning it up

But even with the code working, there’s more that can be done to improve it.

- **You often don't need to specify every intermediate element.**

  Unless there is some ambiguity that needs to be resolved, you can ignore the `<tbody>` and `<td>` elements entirely:

  ```py
  table = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//table[@role='presentation']")
  tr = table.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr[3]")
  strong = tr.find_element_by_xpath(".//strong")
  ```
- **XPath can be overkill.**

  If you're just looking for an element by its tag name, you can avoid XPath entirely:

  ```py
  strong = tr.find_element_by_tag_name("strong")
  ```
- **The fare row may change.**

  Instead of relying on a specific position, you can scope using a text search:

  ```py
  tr = table.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr[contains(text(), 'Base Fare')]")
  ```
- **Other `<table>` elements may be added to the page.**

  If the table had some header text, you could use the same text search approach as with the `<tr>`.

  In this case, it would probably be more meaningful to scope to the `#gdsfarequite` `<div>` rather than something as ambiguous as a `<table>`:

  ```py
  farequote = browser.find_element_by_id("gdsfarequote")
  tr = farequote.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr[contains(text(), 'Base Fare')]")
  ```

But even better, [capybara-py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/capybara-py) provides a nice wrapper on top of Selenium, helping to make this even simpler and clearer:

```py
fare_quote = page.find("#gdsfarequote")
base_fare_row = fare_quote.find("tr", text="Base Fare"):
base_fare = tr.find("strong").text
```

Comment: Ian, Thank you for the answer, Your answer is well detailed and documented. It provides lots of information that is very useful to me. I appreciate you taking the time for such a detailed answer.
Your answer also provides me with the correct solution. 
Thanks Ian! Much Appreciated